# How to get Python files to open into existing Spyder IDE Session

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have been using Spyder via Anaconda for some time, and it has always worked that when I double click on a python file it would open up the code into a new tab in my existing Spyder session. This is on Windows, btw.

I tried a different IDE, Canopy, and it was really awful so I uninstalled it, but somehow in that process I cant get Spyder to get synced back up with my .py files.

When I double click on a .py file, with an existing Spyder session, it will boot up a brand new Spyder session every single time, and it will have an empty black Windows window as well. Neither of these two things was happening to me before I tried out the new IDE.

How can I get back to my .py files opening up into my existing Spyder session? I have tried:

- making sure 'Use single instance' was enabled in Spyder.
- Changing the default app to spyder.exe that is within the Anaconda/Scripts folder
- Changing the default app to both python.exe and pythonw.exe in the Anaconda folder

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Hello, im on 3.2.8.

Comment: We did some changes in 3.2.7 to improve single instance mode on Windows, but some people has reported they instead broke it. We could try to address that in Spyder 3.3.